# Karma detects changes but does not run new tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am using babel and ng-html2js to build and test an angular app with Karma as the test runner. For the most part, things are working. If I make changes to the files, Karma will rerun the tests and pass/fail the tests as appropriately. Karma also determines when changes have been made to the test files themselves ... however, it will run the *old* tests rather than the new tests.

As a simple example:

```
/* constant.js */
angular.module("foo").constant("constant", 1);

/* constant.test.js */
let constant;
beforeEach(inject(_constant_ => constant = _constant));
describe("constant", () => {
  it("is 1", () => {
     expect(constant).to.equal(2);
  });
});
```

In the above test, I am checking `constant` against `2`, but in my original code, `constant` is 1.

- If I change `constant` to `2` in `constant.js`, the test will rerun and pass.
- If I change `.to.equal(2)` to `.to.equal(1)` and rerun the tests from scratch, they will pass.
- If I change `.to.equal(2)` to `.to.equal(1)` while the tests are already running, the tests will rerun automatically *but* they will fail because it is still checking 1 to equal 2.

How can I get Karma to rerun the new tests when I make changes to the test files?

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior with a test that does not use Angular?

Comment: Not sure about not using angular at all, but if the test itself doesn't have any angular constructs the behavior is exactly the same.